# Why are my database tables not generating, my connection string is correct? asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm relatively new to using `mvc`, I have created an application with several models with `scaffold controllers` and `CRUD views`. When running my application on `visual studio's local host` and `localdb` my application works perfectly, however when trying to deploy my application I am receiving an error,

> error processing your request

on the pages associated with my models.

I have deployed my project on a production iis server, and have setup a user login and database on an ms sql server. My project has the correct connection string to interact with the sql server, however when observing the database, my tables associated with my projects models are not being created - which is the route cause of the errors I am receiving.

Is anyone able to suggest why my tables are not being created; below are examples of my code, please note I am also using the asp.net Identity functionality, these tables are also not being created:

Example of one of my models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace newwebsite.Models
{
    public class Store
    {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemImageName { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public string ItemFeatures { get; set; }
}
public class StoreDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Store> Blog { get; set; }

    public StoreDBContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static StoreDBContext Create()
    {
        return new StoreDBContext();
    }
}
}
```

Example of my connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source='MSSqlServerIP'; Initial Catalog=NewWebsite2017; User ID=NewWebsite2017; Password=*****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I've deployed my project all views are working which suggests my controllers for these views are fine. I'm purely getting the error wherever data from the database is supposed to be shown. I believe these errors are due to my tables not being created, but am unsure why this is.

***Update***
I have edited the model (and others in accordingly) as follows, however still have no luck.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace newwebsite.Models
{
public class Store
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemImageName { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public string ItemFeatures { get; set; }
}
public class StoreDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Store> Blog { get; set; }

    public StoreDBContext()
: base("DefaultConnection")
{
        Database.SetInitializer<StoreDBContext>(new    CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<StoreDBContext>());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: And with `Database.SetInitializer<StoreDBContext>(new    DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<StoreDBContext>())` or `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`? (**will delete your data base**)

Answer (score 2):

Specify a DB initializer in your DB context

```
public StoreDBContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection")
{
   Database.SetInitializer<StoreDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<StoreDBContext>());
}
```

There are several other initializers. e.g. `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` or `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` (be careful. this can **delete your data**) or you can program your own initializer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! I'm going to trial this now and I'll let you know if this corrects my error:)

Comment: @Evar If I understand your correct, you don't have any data yet. In this case, did you try ´new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<StoreDBContext>()´ ?

Comment: I haven't tried that, my user database is seeded with an username and password, when logged in I would be able to add data in; no tables have been created on my sql server which is the issue i'm trying to overcome.

Comment: @Evar then you can try it. It recreates all tables in `NewWebsite2017`But doesn't mess with any permissions set

Comment: Unfortunately still no no luck with this suggestion either